# How to override file or function inside node_modules

Tags: angular, npm, node-modules

I need to replace a file from dependency, located in "node_modules". It is not a good practice to amend node_modules directly, as it will be overwritten with next "npm install".
How can I replace such file without touching "node_modules"? For example we can do it with typings. But what about other files?

In my case I want to replace "foo.component.less" and "foo.component.metadata.json" files. Just creating new files in host doesn't help as it would overwrite access to css, but not metadata.

Comment: And who is using `foo.component.less` ? Another module inside `node_modules` ?

Comment: Inside "node_modules" I have foo.component.css. And it creates some conflicts when source maps generation, as all other styles in project are less. Therefore I replace css with less and do appropriate amendments in metadata file. It works fine if to update directly inside node_modules.

Comment: You have to create copy/fork of the package's source code to your own repository. Make the modifications there and then manually add this package to your `package.json` file.

Comment: I had to do something like this for a project. You should be able to use an npm script to accomplish what you want. I blogged about my solution [here](https://blog.pinarydevelopment.com/fullstack/multi-themed-application/semantic-ui-build).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Optimal, but long solution: to create copy/fork of the package's source code:

   - copy/fork of the package's source code;
   - make updates;
   - import to project as dependency instead of original one;
   - update `readme.md` file not to miss in future upgrades.
2. If we don't require to update files and structure entirely, it can be enough to place overriding files to the root of the project(as for `Angular`). For example such `css` file would override the same one in `node_modules`:

   - copy required file to project root;
   - update that file. Now `npm` will look it first.

Comment: is it possible to create a file outside of node_modules that reads the node_modules file and makes a change for that node module file?  I am thinking in regards to a plist file in node-notifier.